# CakePHP AJAX Layout

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'm working with a CakePHP application and jQuery Mobile. In the CakePHP application, RequestHandler is turned on, now, jQuery Mobile makes all of it's requests as ajax requests but requires a full page not just what is in my view but the full layout to.

I need requesthandler and I've tried to set a layout, force a render, turn off autolayout, nothing works, cake only returns the contents of my view.

I'd really love to know what's going on here.

Comment: Why not just modify the ajax layout? Or just use the default layout instead of the ajax layout

Comment: I can't modify that layout because I still want to use it for legitimate ajax requests. Cake is ignoring $this->layout. When I try $this->RequestHandler->renderAs('html') it still does the same thing. I have debug set to 2 and I get no errors.

Comment: try setting the layout in your preRender() callback in your AppController. Could be that something else is switching it back once you set it in the action.

Comment: This didn't work either and for some reason the problem only exists when requesthandler is used, I think something is getting called back on that component and my layout settings are being flat out ignored. The whole frame work is so badly documented.

Comment: You need to step back and walk through the whole process. What you're trying to do is have 1 layout for mobile jquery, 1 layout for ajax and 1 layout for web right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested I found a solution to this, I found out that when you have RequestHandler on and make a Ajax request, it doesn't matter what you do, RequestHandler then decides that your layout is 'ajax' via call backs, this probably applies for all non-html request types, like json and text.

I had to set

```
$this->RequestHandler->enabled = false;
```

It really needs to be set in beforeFilter() as well, latter in the call chain and it appears to not work.

So my code ended up as:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  var $components = array('RequestHandler');
  function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
      $this->RequestHandler->enabled = false
      //set special mobile rules here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to disable the request handler, once you have detected mobile with `isMobile`, you can just change the layout

Comment: That didn't work, the $this->layout = 'default'; assignment is just ignored if I don't disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with a CakePHP 1.3 app that is using jQueryMobile to build mobile-friendly views. I'll try to lay it out for future searches.

When I switched on `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;` for jQM's nice Ajax-based navigation all the linked pages showed `undefined` instead of the page content. The Ajax nav requires that the linked page have the proper structure, like so:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

This markup was coming from two places for my app, though: my default mobile layout had the `<html>`, `<body>` and the `page` and `footer` divs. Each view had a `header` and `content` div.

The problem arose because Cake's RequestHandler wanted to set the layout to `ajax` for all Ajax requests. It does this somewhere **after** `beforeFilter()`, which caused it to ignore a declared layout there (which Luke mentions).

The `ajax` layout is empty, unlike my default layout--it doesn't have `<html>` and other markup because it assumes (rightly) that you only want partial markup that will be inserted into a page by Ajax. The jQuery Ajax-based navigation **does** want to see the full markup though, and when it didn't receive a well-formed page when making the Ajax request it had no page to display.

So the question became, "How do I make RequestHandler use my default mobile layout for mobile page requests?" I wasn't satisfied with Luke's solution above of disabling RequestHandler completely for mobile. Luckily I found a post from May '11 with the same problem and a better solution:

> Finally sorted it!  I was checking to see whether a mobile device was 
>   requesting the page using $this->RequestHandler->isMobile(), but had 
>   placed it in the beforeFilter() function.  Moving this to the 
>   beforeRender() function in the app_controller.php file fixed the 
>   problem.
>   http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Jquery-Mobile-and-CakePHP-1-3-td4422871.html

So my code ended up something like this in AppController:

```
function beforeRender() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
        $this->layout = 'm_default';
    }
}
```

I hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: Sorry for raising an old post.  This looks like a neat solution but when I try it the Ajax post never completes.  It just sits with the "loading" screen interminably.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `$this->layout = 'default';` in your controller, and it will use the default layout.

Or maybe you could make a header and footer [element](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements) to put in your ajax and default layouts.

Comment: Yeah I've done this, for some reason it's just ignored, I think it's performing some kind of callback on requesthandler and ignoring that property.

Answer (score 0):

I was new to CakePHP and started with Version 2 several weeks ago.

So far I also keep the beforeFilter untouched to identifier `isMobile()` and finally use mobile-views within a Themed-Folder. Therefore I dont use subfolders for mobile-views within the default desktop-views. After adding this->layout in the condition it seems that I got rid off the `undefined` which appeared only via some actions links.

```
public function beforeRender() {
    if($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
        $this->theme = 'Mobile';
        $this->layout = 'default';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best sollution I think is to configure the request handler in before filter after the mobile browser was detected in your app controller:

```
public function beforeRender() {
  if($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
      $this->theme = 'Mobile';//set your theme
      $this->RequestHandler->ajaxLayout = 'public';//this does the trick, set your mobile layout, $this->layout is simply ignored or overwritten by the component
  }
}
```