# PHP jQuery mobile listview links return "undefined"

Tags: php, jquery, mobile

I'm using the jQuery Mobile Framework for the first time.  I've copied the example code from the site for a listview.  According to the documentation it is supposed to do an AJAX call and then update the DOM.

When I click on a link the ajax loading icon pops up correctly.  The page then reloads with the only word being "undefined" in it.

I am using CakePHP and it has pulled in my mobile layout.  If I reload the page I get the correct page view.

Can anybody advise where this "undefined" message is coming from and how to get this working?

Thanks,
 Andy

Edit:  Code included

```
// mobile layout 
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">            
    <div class="content-primary">
            <p><?php echo $content_for_layout; ?></p>
    </div><!-- /content -->    
</div><!-- /page -->


// gallery view
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>My heading</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Gauteng',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',4)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Western Cape',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',1)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Eastern Cape',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',2)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Northern Cape',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',9)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Free State',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',3)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Mpumalanga',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',7)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Kwa-Zulu Natal',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',5)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('North West',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',8)); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Limpopo',array('controller'=>'regions','action'=>'gallery',6)); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on any of these results in a page that reads "Undefined".  It has the mobile layout but is not reading the correct viewfile.

Edit:
Googling extensively found a similar problem [answered here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385714/cakephp-ajax-layout) but when I try to change the layout in the beforeRender method then the ajax never completes.  I traced the net traffic with firebug and can see that the http get requests are completing succesfully and returning the correct page info (the whole page). JQM is not updating the view, however.

Comment: Ah, there was a script in the view that was being output.  Removing the script let the site work.

Comment: Sorry to comment again, but I had this problem again and thought that noting the solution here might help people.  The second time I had the problem it was because I was using CakePHP and needed to include the correct div tag at the top of my view file so that the AJAX call would detect the incoming content.

Comment: You may want to post this as an answer and accept it so it appears as if it really is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem again and thought that noting the solution here might help people. The second time I had the problem it was because I was using CakePHP and needed to include the correct div tag at the top of my view file so that the AJAX call would detect the incoming content.