# CakePHP - jQuery Mobile returns empty page containing the word "Undefined"

Tags: jquery, cakephp, mobile

I'm trying to code a Cake site in JQM but whenever I click on a link the screen transitions to a page just containing the word "Undefined".

Examining the source shows that there is a new div with data-role="page" that contains this word, and that the original content of my old page is left intact.

This is my layout for the mobile view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo (isset($title_for_layout)) ? $title_for_layout : 'My default title';?></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php
            // javascript
            $javascripts = array(
                    'jquery',
                    'jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js',
                );
            echo $this->Html->script($javascripts);
            // css
            $css = array('jquery.mobile-1.0.css','jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.css','themes/mobires.css');
            echo $this->Html->css($css) . "\n\t";
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>
                    <?php echo (isset($title_for_layout)) ? $title_for_layout : 'My default title';?>
                </h1>
                 <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Home',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','home'))?></li>
                        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Contact',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','contact'))?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
            </div><!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php
                    echo $this->Session->flash();
                    echo $content_for_layout;
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- start footer -->
                <div data-role="footer">
                    &copy; 2012<?php if ( date("Y") > 2012 ) { echo '-' . date("Y"); } ?> Mobires.  All Rights Reserved.
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Privacy Policy',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','privacy'))?>
                    &nbsp;
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Terms & Conditions',array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'display','terms'))?>

                </div>
        </div><!-- /page -->
        <?php echo $this->Js->writebuffer(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my home.ctp just has the word "test" in it.  I am trying to click the buttons in my footer as a way to test the Ajax loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to integrate cakephp with jquery mobile, in my opinion this is the best solution. Also solves the missed empty pages on cakephp 2.x. You can also see an example of how to get the name of a view file (render file) in cakephp controller with  **Inflector::underscore($this->action)**.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
$this->isMobile = false;
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {

            // required for CakePHP 2.2.2
            $viewDir = App::path('View');
            // returns an array
            /*
             * array(
             *      (int) 0 => '/var/www/maps-cakephp2/app/View/'
             * ) 
             */
             //path to your folder for mobile views . You must modify these lines that you want
             //in my case I have views in folders in to /app/view/mobile and here users folder etc.
            $mobileView = $viewDir[0] .
                    'mobile' . DS . $this->name . DS;
            $mobileViewFile = $mobileView .
                    Inflector::underscore($this->action) . '.ctp';

            if (file_exists($mobileViewFile)) {
                $this->isMobile = true;
                $this->viewPath = 'mobile' . DS . $this->name;

            }

    }
}

public function beforeRender() {
    if ($this->isMobile == true) {
        $this->autorender = true;
        //app/View/Layouts/mobile.ctp
        $this->layout = 'mobile';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the new theme functionality for views in cakephp

Answer (score 1):

Ah, JQM expects a completely formatted JQM response so the entire "page" division must be returned, not just the content.

Comment: Hi Andy. I have the same problem... How did you get completely formatted JQM response in CakePHP???

Comment: Ok, I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385714/cakephp-ajax-layout

Comment: I was just adding the bits of the JQM response that were missing from $content_for_layout by declaring a 'header' and 'footer' element which I output before and after my content.  How did turning off the request handler work for you?

Comment: I set in my AppController::beforeFilter()-function $this->RequestHandler->enabled = false; 

`class AppController extends Controller {
  var $components = array('RequestHandler');
  function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
      $this->RequestHandler->enabled = false
      //set special mobile rules here
    }
  }
}`